# MPNowPlayingInfoCenter doesn't work with the simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I've just been wrestling with `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`. After some time, I could get it working on my iPhone.

But it doesn't work on the simulator (iOS 6 and 7 tested). Am I doing something wrong, or is it explicitly not supported on the simulator?

Answer (score 1):

Note from the Apple docs:

> In iOS Simulator, always include the `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate` key in your nowPlayingInfo dictionary. The simulator uses the value of that key to update the playback progress it displays in Control Center and other simulator-based interfaces. Set the value of the key to 0 for a track that is paused or stopped. Set the value to a positive number for a track that is playing.
>
> *[Event Handling Guide for UIKit Apps: Providing Now Playing Information](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/ProvidingNowPlayingInformation.html)*